# Derivative of Stirling numbers

Tags: partial-derivative, gamma-function, stirling-numbers

I have an optimization problem that involves an Stirling number term $S(n,k;a,b,0)$. The partial derivatives of the "$\log S(n,k;a,b,0)$" will be with respect to all four non-zero parameters $\theta=\{n,k,a,b\}$:

$$\frac{\partial\log S(n,k;a,b,0)}{\partial\theta} = \frac{\frac{\partial S(n,k;a,b,0)}{\partial\theta}}{S(n,k;a,b,0)}$$

as-is, this is a pretty nasty derivative to deal with. I wonder if the derivatives of the Stirling numbers have been studied any where? I am considering both forms of Stirling number representation: recursive, or explicit.

[I am dreaming of a nice and tight bound around the Stirling number and dealing with taking the derivatives over that bound.]

Comment: Given that the parameters are (usually) integer valued, first-order differences would seem more natural than derivatives, no?

Comment: I recently came to the same conclusion, but couldn't find any scientific reference for justifying it ...